# Is it possible to wrap the tag into a variable?

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a component that I want to reuse, and in different instances, I want different icons that come with different tags "Entypo" and "AntDesign". I would like to switch them on type property. Here is the idea:

```
const tag = type === 'home' ? 'Entypo' : 'AntDesign';
<{tag} name='someName' />
```

But it doesn't go through. Is there something I am missing? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Entypo` and `AntDesign` are components (eg. imported from `react-native-vector-icons`), then you should be able to do it like so:

```
const Tag = type === 'home' ? Entypo : AntDesign;

<Tag name='someName' />
```

Comment: That works! It is interesting though, if the variable name is lower case "tag" as opposed to "Tag", then it doesn't work. If the tag name is capitalised as shown in your example, it is fine

Comment: Note that this is not the only difference, though - in your example, `tag` is a string, not a component, and `<{tag} ...` is (afaik) not a valid syntax.